# Best way to handle a group of arguments being exclusive/required with argparse?

Tags: python, arguments, parameter-passing, argparse, required

So I have four arguments. --A, --B, --C, --D. --A is considered "by itself", while --B, --C and --D can be in a group together. If one of B/C/D is present than the rest of B/C/D can be considered required as well (mutually exclusive group?).

In addition, I want it so that either --A is required OR the group of BCD is required, not both. When one isn't present the other is required. I've been using various combinations of mutually exclusive groups and required arguments but keep running into errors.

Most of the ways I found to handle this end up utilizing the 'required' flag and a separate functions or weird conditionals, but I was wondering if there was a good way to handle this with the tools of the argparse itself. I was able to do it with having "required = '--A' not in sys.argv" for each of BCD, but would rather handle it in tandem with the arguments being put together rather than looking at the text passed in through sys if I could. Having "required = '--A' not in parser.parse_known_args()[0].**dict**" for each of BCD seems to work as well but just seems like a weird solution for something that should be able to be handled within the tools of argparse. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is there any way to combine the values for B & C & D into a single thing, so you could use a single flag (for example, BCD) for them?

Comment: No, `argparse` does not provide ways of doing fancy combinations of grouped arguments.  There's the obvioius mutually_exclusive_group, but that's a simple XOR among a set of arguments.  There's no 'nesting' of groups within that.  But if the defaults are all `None`, then it's easy to test after parsing whether certain combinations have been provided.  Or give all arguments meaningful defaults, in which case you won't care whether they have been supplied or not.

Comment: Not really, BCD are all gonna have individual parameters associated with themselves as well. Even then I could wrap them up I suppose but with the context the program is being used with I need to keep the command-line arguments the same as they would have been originally.

Comment: Keep in mind when designing a parsing, that you have to explain it to your end user.  `argparse` is set up to display a `usage` with simple XOR, but nothing fancy.  Remmber, your primary goal is to figure out what the end user wants.

Answer (score 0):

This is a complex requirement. I have tried different approaches and none of them perfect as M.G. found. However, if we go handle the validation ourselves instead of letting argparse does it, it can be simpler.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--A")
parser.add_argument("--B")
parser.add_argument("--C")
parser.add_argument("--D")

options = parser.parse_args()
print(options)

# Validate: A XOR (B AND C AND D)
if options.A and any([options.B, options.C, options.D]):
    raise SystemExit("--A is present, cannot have --B, --C, and --D")
if options.A is None and not all([options.B, options.C, options.D]):
    raise SystemExit("--B, --C, --D must be together and all required")
```

Sample runs:

```bash
# --B on its own
$ python3 main.py --B boy
Namespace(A=None, B='boy', C=None, D=None)
--B, --C, --D must be together and all required

# Missing --D
$ python3 main.py --B boy --C charlie                    
Namespace(A=None, B='boy', C='charlie', D=None)
--B, --C, --D must be together and all required

# All are present
$ python3 main.py --B boy --C charlie --D delta --A apple
Namespace(A='apple', B='boy', C='charlie', D='delta')
--A is present, cannot have --B, --C, and --D

# Happy path: --A
$ python3 main.py --A apple        
Namespace(A='apple', B=None, C=None, D=None)

# Happy path: --B, --C, and --D
$ python3 main.py --B boy --C charlie --D delta          
Namespace(A=None, B='boy', C='charlie', D='delta')
```